# file_get_contents($url) returns something that is totally different from the source

Tags: php

What I want to do is get the webpage and leech some info from it. The code worked fine for a while but now it returns something that can not be displayed in a browser.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://thepiratebay.com/");
echo $html;
```

For a while this code just mirrored the webpage I requested but now I get the following:

`‹½[{sÛ¸ÿ;ù°f®¶ç,ÊzØIlI7–±ÇQcçÕ›+"!EÐ(EIóÝ»H ©¯SöæbìþvÅbABÝ‹wç_†—È3¿ÿ¼+ÈÇÁ¤W#AMvûÏü×‘ãáˆÑ«Åb\YKš>é_°Eà3ì¢YÌ©s€flN ?@<“ÎÆb#²ƒ<‚†4Â‚ ^¢º"L°¿.w9°q"Â©OI Ð€ŠE²È© Ý†3t @~¯æîD4”5ä°@G¯VR'„ÙÅñ CD¬M )G¢¼ŠV-¯Ý”,,r¹¡Ú,l <§hD…Ðüh³ÀW:'&$ªã0ô©ƒ¥½ºÝÄÚ‡úÉa¾Èš²Îi†'Q2U¡@Ñ cŸÔ¥õ9‰è8Á0]¾ÿBØìæüˆ>ùÃÛ8¿¿¼>{õz~öáÍ·«k¯ýéfÑê|s ÄN½þ;#_ ›KôêMU-> ¦0˜~¯ÆÅÒ'Ü# ò"2îÕ\ºÓp8¯dÑ Ä‚bÍàÖ“Žxä¬z?ò†tä#{Ì"X£ÛÐ=Su~'KÇÔë á¯h1Ã40ô0y Ž¯†Ä2„±4¦¨ÁBèVÃQý:ó3UK‘•Ÿ÷j÷Š´á‘ydìÐ¬åek8•. 1ž ìË»’ü|žççsûþ²$0Êó#ûî]Yþýƒ <¿‹óü.¶/Þ”äÓ<ÿ˜ÚW7%ù)ÏóSnßÜ—µß/°ß·ïnËÚO ì'öEÙù£¢@aß<”õ¿û ·/ËÚà‡Â–ÅßÂ?x_vþ£‚ùì«²üaÁü…¾=,;^œç÷bûúCÙñ/À'¾ýº¬þ¢À~Ùeù£ý£Ø~_V>-ˆ?Sû¾ìúu Ö¿ƒËûŸW°~|DÜc‹ŠðŽsx×8p=â»Õà½Èã]Tì¬/‹!«×W9ÐöE%H¯òH•Å²¶¹¹ïÏªÁjb}ŸhàV4qms³]G}‹+ÙÞÛæ^»Žøáîæs5mU.þ¶Ü6`oÞÝ£=:Änƒ=ýjð·áŸnÄh5V›ÉÆ:ªZ§èÝÏOÓÿ%lÇXª¯åïj@šë `Ô°’”­c¬Ë©¢Ù1dfÔý×j :9¨ÏƒwŸÛÇ‡ÕÀåà>QZ ÔqªÊØÒ1‹ïÿT:Fz‘WM:F4Iá*ÛîŒ2dQP Fs £Ò\ðÈˆ"k`•[ŽŒ`’ ©#â¨*;›p•ÿ##š$X§òGFP1§¯ºóØ‘±ÜÄÊVÛ±±Ú*i®ƒ€E—õÊ^$.…;g3êT„ÖÎ¡U¹ÚŽÕ¶²nN¢ŠÐŽòÖyKNG~EæÎŸ¦Žù¼ÛÐW[º#æ.ááÒ9¢n¯6SU¼f¿‹S€µ—Ë›ßâ»<ÄAÚm(b·áˆÒ2¬Qà)-]¿É "Lúé÷þäúÈÑtôïU×•Zœ#Éê­·ªf¼µþAjS('"´grÞ«ª!gƒ°UŽ˜¯){=‘–4*`S7[2ÎäM´zlGbá Š…H¾7ï'É¤Ç»Ç,š%w\žjhF„Ç`"&òv¤SÉ{ sBB5U4 ¢jR,V²´{fW?’h«=á>¡†>vˆÇ|—D¹66fNÌÁñŸbwOyÒi},8‚¾:™räÂ2*ÙÀËI¿ÑdrnHÉŠJÆ³g]:Ž`ôÅOˆð¤ÑX,Öì”áØrØ¬úñ„¼áÓ)±B/üMÉÞ¿´Ï~i]Áÿ‹öoxžúxÉbÑÅB°ÀvXE—^dKÞQ¬û&s'TÝa>‹¸ã˜ŸN<ÅYCêRO¯¶ ®ðNÀEÂ¯§‘Í'-Y†NÄ|X“òÖ«!eÜˆEj¾`_Ã¾Ï`.äX.åÇñ˜È{Ez Ô˜¤#)-ä0 bAD15ê&V ¶zÌ90ë–º¢Öµ¥5äbëqäg#º1:IA¾ ˜:u‘ð(G!ÌŒe%ÍæžÀ@Éxai,éÜ%W¡vÆq †oÏ=àÔÝÿ>ÇzäãGÞs-X—>Œ#,øÁòOîÀÌ=¾ÿûáa¯ñ/­¢%{®å3š÷Û• »'êÁwOéxoÇ”5XÞ¸{€µÿ]8“6~úÈ-XvÔ•é\á¯»0°~„\Á–9¤0› —[*[jjÄs‰^G"1 ÀCö´Eû§?~ì¹°Îfê~Ý®„](¥“±Aû§ë7Å²UÒX_…ÝF˜Ž7Ú>ßüdÁü—O x÷Ñ±DrcÙÊÈ©'ºïíŸ¦ñ\Ú™ŽØWp!Y‚ íÝ†ø)¨úˆhÂ>e°:„aÝCé ‹™Ñl‹}%¶¼þddÂ/6àçº‡„OŠ%à•Ø2Ö›oyM-Èæ „ë1P¥2C`È.¡Š>È˜:D:Lt©DR,¡…[^€Mt±ª\—J`K™% uÒeb/7°™î!Á“b t%6_´0y<šoâÉÞ íTlÛ»çØóTÃþdßìÎÐ!r§A·±3]Ö’!ðu%Ëwû „G]W^õLæQíà‰œÃò|j³­T€ì¹`T» †“²NMÕÃÖìú5#cöˆ¿ÊÐ®Ù¹Ýd7”«õó4,'ù.dè“ÃcÌçU ;˜‘²0H0VùŠªõÕ#ÉŸ™Iî„r!+KsB?-å™r9Ñ=ñ‰#PFÏ2#Ô@myix‰ÍêuºªõÕ£™Lðêð­¬Áf/·K™Ž™Õ‹]È®Òâ6…yF†®ZÀ‹â™¡ùgZë+ò6AIJ§Îu:Ú[úÈåÅ¦ÌµnÙrÛâ *¨>¦0"–üÑ@æW q;TÚc ¥È*OgiŽ)ýf6ÉËÖô­Ãƒ¹N–ME‡’(Oê9aiË6q°ÃˆyN\Ä¾É’äLÐN½ŽrÒŒÜU„#— pÃä=°ù¡Ý·È; º%Gkùk†ü)$w,{ðHâxù Go±ãÑ€lQä*áü3MÒ~…‡ïôíŠü!…Ü-­ãæ!üë 4("‰8º…)Aq' µš'Ã“ÃcK;æQÇj½8´_¡ÈÎ{¦uÜnZ/:Ä q%íWÔlñ¥Õn7‘O$ßG4@ÇV«ýÂj5_e?®IäjuÕv³¦.uôåÝ+ç´T8Œ–žD3üôTœ3½ îhÅšðœ4ßï\þñmê^Ÿ·XÜž„Ë××OÎíüæÛâaËŸ÷Ñ&ˆ/ÔÏ§‚lSðÚ SÎ”åä–~ Û“fóîh0ùøòéÍ§N+ÝÿóóÕìñb°|d¥Œ?ë£ôÓº©¿ÏÌÝ˜¯"éûûûìdÌC$›’—jÐb¾IKÂSá~ ã¤\s›Â½IšWˆ CªÛ Üç†ƒÈH'$é1úù3:F{‚…h§^è÷Á¿ÂìDlIMQ­ÕOŸ?Kß(=ê}ÃtLÏ¨–Ì´¸õd‘ä~*;XêŒf%‡ÀÞûœèuz*j'š"º:d5¨<×ðÃÐ9ÉÊ¿oWÖ‚óì†ôãùêp ~«ß¼6ôoÿ,ˆŸOŒ8`

I dont understand it.

Comment: That's a torrent of the new Godzilla.

Comment: try gzdecode(file_get_contents(... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl to fetch data correctly.curl is much faster than file_get_contents()

getContents returns the data fetched.

```
function getContent($url)
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0",
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Guess now I have to read up on this curl thingy. Thank you for saving me from frustration.

Answer (score 2):

This is because GZIP compression is on. You need to use CURL or define http context, so it would send `accept-encoding: gzip;q=0,deflate,sdch` header...

Would be something like this:

```
$opts = array(
   'http'=>array(
      'method'=>"GET",
      'header'=>"Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0,deflate,sdch\r\n"
   )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.thepiradebay.com', false, $context);
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work or rather it worked just like before.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function get_url($url) {
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8rn" .
                        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdchrn" .
                        "Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5rn" .
                        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.4rn"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $content = file_get_contents($url ,false,$context);

    foreach($http_response_header as $c => $h){
        if(stristr($h, 'content-encoding') and stristr($h, 'gzip')){
            $content = gzinflate( substr($content,10,-8) );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}

echo get_url('http://www.thepiratebay.com/');
```